# how to make a map of properties using formatted string "Property:Value"

Tags: java

Lets say we created a string formatted like this "Property:Value". How do we put this formatted string into a map in Java like this `HashMap<JoystickEnum,String>` where `Property` is an `enum` and the value is a `string`. Currently I am working on a project where we recieve input using this formatted string. My enum is called `JoystickEnum`. The class is called `Joystick` and it extends the Controller class.NOTE: Since we will be using this abstract class that is going to be implemented in multiple controllers. This class has code,

```java
    public String data;
    public InputStream dataStream;
    private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[400];
    public enum InputMode {
            POLL,EVENT
    };
    public InputMode mode = InputMode.EVENT;
    public InputHandler(InputStream dataStream) {
        
        this.dataStream = dataStream;
    }
    @Override
    public abstract void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0);
    public void setDataMode(InputMode mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    public abstract void poll();

    public abstract Map getData();
    @Override
    public abstract void run();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

The `InputMode` enum just contains `POLL,EVENT`. Where the code will go is in the extended method `getData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if *data* is a String of the format "Property:Value" and *map* an object of type Map<JoystickEnum, String> you can add an entry as follow

```
String[] dataArray = data.split(":");
map.put(JoystickEnum.valueOf(dataArray[0]), dataArray[1]);
```

assuming that *Property* match with an enum value and *Value* won't contain any ":"